# juju ssh public key issue

Tags: 12.04, ssh, juju

I have two machines on which one is running a postgresql charm and other is running the charm I'm working on. Now I need to ssh into the postgresql machine to run some database migration scripts. For unknown reasons, the charm fails when it tries to ssh to the postgresql machine.

```
ssh ubuntu@10.0.3.59
Permission denied (publickey).
```

10.0.3.59 is the IP for postgresql machine. I've scoured the internet for public key issue and done everything from generating a public key myself to copying it to the other machine but even ssh-copy-id throws error of public key. If i try to ssh from a juju machine into any other non-juju machine it works smoothly.

Anyone ever faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `juju ssh` [command](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.25/charms-working-with-units) instead, like `juju ssh postgres/0`. Check out the user guide

Comment: Well my question was regarding ssh to another juju machine from inside a juju machine. So juju ssh won't work inside the juju created machine.

Answer (score 0):

Juju doesn't setup ssh authentication between units of a service. The only ssh authentication it sets up is between the node where you ran bootstrap and the service units that you deployed.